# What is the core difference between Bootstrap CSS and AngularJS UI Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

So I am developing a new MVC application using AngularJS and I wanted to implement bootstrap for the UI but upon searching for bootstrap from within NuGet I see AngularJS UI Bootstrap.

I did a little reading to find that this unfamiliar flavor of Bootstrap could actually serve as a replacement for the traditional bootstrap that I am more familiar with but I really don't understand what the core difference is of when one would opt to use one over the other.

So what are the advantages of using AngularJS UI Bootstrap instead of Bootstrap? Given my current stated position for what I am doing, would it be more advantageous to use AngularJS UI Bootstrap or is it purely a matter of personal preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Angular UI-bootstrap` is a replacement for the Bootstrap javascript, not for the css framework. It has rebuild the bootstrap JS functionalities such as modals and popovers to 'the Angular way', so if you want to use those functionalities use `Angular UI-bootstrap`

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that it wouldn't suffice as a total replacement.